# "Implicit Conversion Loses Integer Precision" error

Tags: iphone, zxing

I have this code and get the following error: `Implicit Conversion Loses Integer Precision`

```
size_t BitArray::wordsForBits(size_t bits) {
  int arraySize = (bits + bitsPerWord_ - 1) >> logBits_;
  return arraySize;    
}
```

How can I resolve this?